# Several symfony project on one server with the same port

Tags: apache, symfony

I have a trouble installing two projects on the same server. Some necessary information:

1. One VPS server
2. Two symfony projects (each in separate directory)
3. Subdomains pointing to projects (first.domain.com / second.domain.com)
4. All projects must be on the same port (80)

My server looks like this:

```
   Root directory: /var/www/html
     - index.php (welcome page)
     - projecta (first project)
     - projectb (second project)
```

I would like to achieve:

```
    domain.com -> index.php
    first.domain.com (domain.com/first) -> first project
    second.domain.com (domain.com/second) -> second project
```

My apache config:

```
Alias "/first" "/var/www/html/projecta/web"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vps.net
    ServerAlias http://vps.net/first

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/projecta/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/projecta/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ first/app.php [QSA]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/first_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/first_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Alias "/second" "/var/www/html/projectb/web"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vps.net
    ServerAlias http://vps.net/second

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/projectb/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/projectb/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ projectb/app.php [QSA]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/second_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/second_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that first project override path to second project (if I change first project server, then second works).

Now looks like:

```
domain.com -> first project
domain.com/first -> first project
domain.com/second -> second project in web directory (when I click on the app.php then project run).
```

---

#### Solved

I **solved** the problem in this way (only in apache config file, I don't need any .htaccess file)

```
Alias "/first" "/var/www/html/projecta/web"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName first.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.first.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/projecta/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/projecta/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ first/app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/first_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/first_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Alias "/second" "/var/www/html/projectb/web"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName second.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.second.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/projectb/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/projectb/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ second/app.php [QSA]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/second_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/second_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Currently alias didn't work, but for the moment it is enough.

Comment: I did this at my work, I'll check how I did it tomorrow, think it has to do with htaccess file.